# Looking for an example of surjective map between rings such that Jacobson radical containment is strict

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A,B$ be rings. Let $f:A\to B$ be surjective ring homomorphism. Denote $Jac(A)$ as the jacobson radical of $A$. $I\cdot A[[x]]$ for ideal $I\subset A$ denotes the ideal of $A$ generated ideal in $A[[x]]$.

Then $f(Jac(A))\subset Jac(B)$. This is trivial to see by characterization of jacobson radical elements. I am stucked at looking for an example for strict containment. I think it might have something to do with infinite variable formal series. Consider $A=K[[x_1,x_2,\dots ]]$ infinite indeterminates polynomial ring over field $K$. It has a maximal ideal not f.g. $(x_1,\dots)$. I want to consider $B=K[[x_2,\dots, ]]$. Then $f:A\to B$ by evaluating $x_1=0$. This is $A/(x_1)\cong B$.

Q1. What is the example that this containment is strict?

Q2. The apparent fact is that if ideal $I\subset A$ is not f.g., and consider the ideal $I[[x]]$ set of polynomials with coefficients in $I$, it is clear that $I[[x]]\supset I\cdot A[[x]]$. What is the example that this containment is strict? It seems that I think they are the same thing as somehow I can rearrange terms and put elements of $I[[x]]$ into $I\cdot A[[x]]$ though the latter can be only finite sum of products between $A[[x]]$ and $I$ elements.

Comment: Isn't the canonical projection $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ an example?

Comment: @egreg I think I might have made this too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether playing with formal power series in an infinite number of variables will help in finding the example, but there is a much simpler one.

A local ring has its only maximal ideal as its Jacobson radical and the simplest local ring is $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. The projection $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ provides the example.